# unable to validate weblogic domain

Tags: jsf, weblogic-10.x

I am new to JSF, was setting up my first workspace in Eclipse Helios and Weblogic 10.0 server, I am getting 'Stopped, Unable to validate weblogic domain' while trying to start the server. Same problem persists while trying to add a new domain.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WebLogic server 12c and the steps to resolve this issue is:

1. Start Weblogic server(I started through command prompt)
2. Go to Weblogic console page (login with admin credentials)
3. Domain Structure >> Select your domain (i was having base_domain)
4. Click on the Security tab
5. Check Anonymous Admin Lookup enabled. (by default its unchecked)
6. Save (save the changes)

** Restart the server (preferably through admin console)

Now, Start the server through eclipse. It should work.!!

Regards,

Maris

Comment: I tried to do this but didn't help. Still the same problem.

Comment: I have tested the above steps on Welogic 12c.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the resolution :
Go to Window Tab -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections
Change the Active provider to "Direct". The default is usually Native.  and that's  it. Close and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well, I even reinstalled weblogic again, after a bit of research I decided to kill all of the Java(TM) Platform SE Binary process via Task Manager and restarted the Server.

That's all It took to resolve the issue.

I tested this on Weblogic 10.3.6. Luck!!